# Angular with npm or visual studio?

Tags: c#, angular, npm, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to to create a UI project using angular 6,
What approach is better, do I have to create angular project using npm or go with visual studio angular template?
This UI is consuming Web API's written using Dot net Core 2.1

I created sample UI project using both I couldn't find out any great difference.

Comment: Use Angluar CLI for bootstrapping the project. It will help to maintain version upgrades and any other orchestration you need to do with your project. Also you can implement custom schematics on top of it if needed.

Comment: This depends solely on you, your project, and your team. This kind of question attracts opinionated answers, so you should really make the decision on your own.

Comment: Annoying thing about the Angular & .netcore template in VS is that the Angular version is really outdated. If you don't want to use the VS template, you can use Task Runner explorer to bind the building of webpack on project build which is very handy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729639/dotnet-vs-angular-cli

Comment: Expect your question to get closed as [“off-topic” ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) but until then, the answer is “it depends”... small app? I may use the template for demo purposes, for larger production apps I’d write the api and the ui separately

Answer (score -1):

I think, best of all to use VisualStudio. It's more comfortable for me, but use the one, that you like better, as it's only the tool.